# Java / MongoTemplate Aggregation, Group and Sum not grouping as expected

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a mongo collection which has many documents containing information about credits / gifts given to our users.

I would like to be able to run an Aggregated Query to get all the users who have received a credit / gift within the last x number of days and sum the total value of those credits for each user.

I think I have the correct Aggregation, group and sum code but I'm getting back more than one object per user, which shouldn't be the case since I'm grouping and then summing the values(?)

Here is what my document structure looks like:

```
    _id: ObjectId("61c36a8a21047124c4181271"),
    transactionId: UUID("6fbf536e-7a53-442c-9615-53e32362608b"),
    userId: 'xxxxx',
    transactionMessage: 'Account credited with: 1',
    transactionType: 'CREDIT',
    transactionAction: 'GIFT',
    inComingPaymentFromUserId: 'xxxx',
    transactionAmount: Decimal128("1"),
    customMessage: "blah'",
    createdDate: ISODate("2021-12-22T18:12:26.812Z"),
    lastUpdatedAt: ISODate("2021-12-22T18:12:26.812Z"),
```

And here is my query code:

```java
    @Override
    public List<RecentlyRewardedUsers> findRecentlyRewardedUsers(Integer range, Pageable pageable) {
        Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
                match(Criteria.where("createdDate").gt(LocalDate.now().minusDays(range))
                        .andOperator(Criteria.where("transactionAction").is("GIFT"))), sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "createdDate"),
                group("userId", "_id").sum("transactionAmount").as("totalValueAwarded"),
                project("userId", "totalValueAwarded"),
                skip((long) pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize()),
                limit(pageable.getPageSize()));
        try {
            return mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "Transactions", RecentlyRewardedUsers.class).getMappedResults();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ServiceUnavailableException("Unable to perform Mongo Operation {" + ex.getLocalizedMessage() + "}", "User");
        }
    }
```

Here is also my mapped class:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
public class RecentlyRewardedUsers {

    @Field("userId")
    private String userId;
    private String totalValueAwarded;
    private String userDisplayName;
    private String profilePicUrl;
}
```

Like I said above, when the the results of the query are mapped to the RecentlyRewardedUsers class, I see multiple entries for the same userId (see image below). I would have thought it should be all rolled up / summed up into one entry for that userId

[image]

If anyone can shed some light on what I've done wrong that would be great!!

Thank you

** EDIT **
Based on the answer below from
user Eskandar Abedini, I've updated my code to be the following:

```java
Criteria operator = new Criteria();
operator.andOperator(
        Criteria.where("createdDate").gt(LocalDate.now().minusDays(2))
                .andOperator(Criteria.where("transactionAction").is("GIFT")));

MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(operator);


GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("userId").sum("transactionAmount").as("totalValueAwarded");
List<String> sortOptions = new ArrayList<>();
sortOptions.add("createdDate");
Sort sort = new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, sortOptions);
SortOperation sortOperation = Aggregation.sort(sort);

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Transaction.class, matchOperation, groupOperation, sortOperation);

AggregationResults<RecentlyRewardedUsers> aggregationResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Transaction.class, RecentlyRewardedUsers.class);
```

When I now execute the above I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid reference 'createdDate'!
```

If for the moment I remove the sort options. The code will execute. However I'm not getting the userId mapped into my RecentlyRewarded class.

```
Criteria operator = new Criteria();
operator.andOperator(
        Criteria.where("createdDate").gt(LocalDate.now().minusDays(2))
                .andOperator(Criteria.where("transactionAction").is("GIFT")));

MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(operator);


GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("userId").sum("transactionAmount").as("totalValueAwarded");
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Transaction.class, matchOperation, groupOperation);

AggregationResults<RecentlyRewardedUsers> aggregationResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Transaction.class, RecentlyRewardedUsers.class);
```

Any help would be amazing.

Thank you

**Edit**
Adding image to show what I mean by userId not being mapped in the MappedResponse. However in the Raw response of the query the userId is getting mapped to the documentId _id

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `_id` from `group("userId", "_id")`

This is somehow similar to yours, its implementation is clear too.

```
public BaseResponse getErrorLogGroupByAppName() throws BaseException {

    Criteria operator = new Criteria();
    operator.andOperator(
            Criteria.where("execDate").is(DateUtil.today())
    );

    MatchOperation matchOperation = Aggregation.match(operator);


    GroupOperation groupOperation = Aggregation.group("serUrl", "serPort", "appName", "appSer", "reqUrl", "execDate").count().as("count");

    Sort sort = new Sort(new Sort.Order(Sort.Direction.DESC, "count"));
    SortOperation sortOperation = Aggregation.sort(sort);

    Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(ErrorInfo.class, matchOperation, groupOperation, sortOperation);

    AggregationResults<Map> aggregationResults = template.aggregate(aggregation, ErrorInfo.class, Map.class);

    return new BaseResponse(aggregationResults.getMappedResults());
}
```

[GitHub Source](https://github.com/7040210/SuperBoot/blob/master/super-boot-global/src/main/java/org/superboot/service/impl/ErrorLogServiceImpl.java#L35)

Comment: Thanks for the response! But if I remove that I'm unable to map the class to the results i.e. the userId is null

Comment: As I see `_id` is credit / gift id not user id and should be removed for grouping to act as expected. Grouping on credit / gift id causes all credits / gifts to be in output.

Comment: Ok thank you I'll be back at the laptop in a few hours and I'll try this and let you know. Once again thank you for the help.

Comment: Ok so I'm getting a slightly different error now.

Comment: I'll update the question if you can take a look please again @Eskandar

Comment: FYI, I've also tried adding projection to get the userId out with no success :-/

Comment: For now use your original code, just remove `_id` from grouping then go in debug mode and evaluate `mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, Transaction.class, RecentlyRewardedUsers.class);` result without assigning it to any variable.

Comment: Ok so using the original code, when I remove "_id" and then debug when I look at the result, I see userId is null but totalValueAwarded is correct.

Comment: So continue with correcting this problem.

Comment: Replace `_id` with `userId` till finding the problem origin! `group("userId", "userId")`

Comment: Then gradually replace this code with structured one.

Comment: Ok, so I now have this working but only by annotating the userId field in the RecentlyRewardedUsers.class with @Id

Comment: Any idea why this would be?

Comment: Simplify problem, remove any field form grouping, projection and order by, just try getting distinct user Ids then step by step add other parts of aggregation. Please note that you should remove date form order by clause because it causes duplicates and error, a single user may have received gifts in different days that causes duplicates.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try again so. "a single user may have received gifts in different days that causes duplicates" -- But this is what I want. Users can get multiple gifts on the same day or over several days. Basically I want the sum of the amounts for the users grouped by their userId in the specified range

Comment: Btw, I genuinely appreciate your time and help